# How to correlate NDVI and Land Surface Temperature in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, ndvi, correlation

I'm looking for ways to correlate the NDVI values and the land surface temperature values that I have on QGIS. I'm kind of new at using these kinds of programs. I'm working on a thesis and for my results I want to know the correlation between NDVI and LST.

How can I do this in QGIS or how can I do it in any other program?

Keep in mind I don't know much about GIS in general.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want I recommend you to use **SAGA**, it is very easy and direct.

**SAGA** is automatically installed with QGIS. If you are in windows go to `start > all programs > QGIS 3 > SAGA GIS`

I answered a similar question here, Click on the link and you will see a detailed description [Calculating correlation between points and raster values with missing points (need missing as 0s) (QGIS)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374153/calculating-correlation-between-points-and-raster-values-with-missing-points-ne/374178#374178)

Comment: Muchas Gracias por responder Luis. Estoy usando Mac, sabes como seria el proceso aqui, y en caso contrario, puedo descargarlo online?

Comment: @Manuel Esteban , En mac QGIS no instala SAGA? debería estar disponible en las aplicaciones. De no estar puedes entrar a la pagina  saga-gis.org y descarga la versión que desees.

Comment: @ManuelEsteban si la respuesta fue útil, soluciono tu problema, coloca una valoración con las flechas (triángulos) ubicados a la izquierda. Y cerrar la pregunta. También puedes calcular la correlación con PyQGIS pero tendrías que editar la pregunta para que pueda agregar otra respuesta.

Comment: Una pregunta Luis, para correlacionar NDVI y TST es el mismo proceso con el cual respondiste la pregunta del link ''I answered a similar question here, Click on the link and you will see a detailed description Calculating correlation between points and raster values with missing points (need missing as 0s) (QGIS)''? y si sabes donde podria conseguir mas info de la app seria excelente, muchisimas gracias otra vez Luis!

Comment: Si, el procedimiento es para correlacionar dos raster o correlacionar un raster con puntos con valores de otra variable. Se aplica de igual forma para cualquier variable numérica.